# unable to bind data to input field

Tags: angular

I am using reactive forms in my Angular App. I want to bind data to an input field of type button. I want its default value to be "testdata".i am unable to bind the data to the input field. please guide me. Thanks.

I am trying to get the data from API and display on front end using formControlName.

HTML

```
<form  [formGroup]='form'>
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
              <input class='pl-2 ' nbInput fullWidth type="button"
                     formControlName='data'>
            </div>
</form
```

TS

```
export class dataComponent implements OnInit {
selecteddata: string;
form: FormGroup;
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.form= this.FormBuilder.group {
data: [""],
}
this.form.controls.data.setvalue('testdata');
}
```

Comment: `selecteddata` variable used in the template is not same as declared in the `ts` file

Comment: Also, why do you need to use a formControl on the button?

Comment: @YoannPicquenot please check the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @rja You can use the value attribute like you did to set the value of the button. Do you intend to use validators on this input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use patch value instead of setvalue. like This

```
this.form.patchValue({data:'testdata'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo with default value as `testdata`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-example-1

But not sure why you are using formControl on a button using reactive forms.

Comment: Hey thanks. but how can i do it without using Value. i want to set vvalue by using FormControlName.

Answer (score 0):

I made codesandbox example using your example. Hope it is what you are looking for.

https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-wave-q1oqs?file=/src/app/app.component.ts